# Failed conversion from dwg to svf with the Autocad api TranslationWorker

Tags: autodesk-forge

I am failing to upload a simple dwg and convert it to svf using the TranslationWorker from the forge API. I am using autocad 2014 and creating a simple drawing with a circle and saving it as a .dwg.

I am using the commandline in windows and the following curl commands:

```
curl -v "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/oss/v2/buckets/kumkortbucket/objects/sirkel.dwg" -X "PUT" -H "Authorization: Bearer OAUTH_TOKEN" -H "Content-Type: application/octet-stream" -T "‪C:\Users\DAN\Documents\Testfiler\sirkel.dwg"
```

which produces the following result:

```
HTTP/1.1 100 Continue
* We are completely uploaded and fine
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
< Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Authorization, Accept-Encoding, Range,Content-Type
< Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET
< Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
< Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
< Date: Tue, 14 Feb 2017 12:56:38 GMT
< Server: Apigee Router
< Content-Length: 355
< Connection: keep-alive
<
{
  "bucketKey" : "kumkortbucket",
  "objectId" : "urn:adsk.objects:os.object:kumkortbucket/sirkel.dwg",
  "objectKey" : "sirkel.dwg",
  "sha1" : "78f92dc0a364814756cfa9392d7fa95aecf0916b",
  "size" : 31548,
  "contentType" : "application/octet-stream",
  "location" : "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/oss/v2/buckets/kumkortbucket/objects/sirkel.dwg"
}* Connection #0 to host developer.api.autodesk.com left intact
```

I then convert it using the POST job command

```
curl -X "POST" -H "Authorization: Bearer OAUTH_TOKEN" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -v "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/designdata/job" -d "{\"input\": {\"urn\": \"dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6a3Vta29ydGJ1Y2tldC9zaXJrZWwuZHdn\"},\"output\": {\"formats\": [{\"type\": \"svf\",\"views\": [\"2d\",\"3d\"]}]}}"
```

Using the GET command to check the result i get the following result:

{"type":"manifest","hasThumbnail":"false","status":"failed","progress":"complete","region":"US","urn":"dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6a3Vta29ydGJ1Y2tldC9zaXJrZWwuZHdn","version":"1.0","derivatives":[{"name":"sirkel.dwg","hasThumbnail":"false","status":"failed","progress":"complete","messages":[{"type":"error","code":"AutoCAD-InvalidFile","message":"Sorry, the drawing file is invalid and cannot be viewed. \n- Please try to recover the file in AutoCAD, and upload it again to view."},{"type":"error","message":"Unrecoverable exit code from extractor: -1073741831","code":"TranslationWorker-InternalFailure"}],"outputType":"svf"}]}* Connection #0 to host developer.api.autodesk.com left intact

I cannot figure out what i am doing wrong. I can view the file in autocad and the online viewer.

Cheers.

EDIT:

here is a file that is problematic to upload
http://www.filedropper.com/ekbsroplain

Comment: when you say it works on online viewer, do you mean this https://a360.autodesk.com/viewer/ ?

Comment: Yes, it uploads fine in that viewer. @AugustoGoncalves

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is what I did (entire process):

```
curl -v 'https://developer.api.autodesk.com/authentication/v1/authenticate' -X 'POST' -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' -d 'client_id=****&client_secret=****&grant_type=client_credentials&scope=data:read data:write data:create bucket:create bucket:read'

curl -v 'https://developer.api.autodesk.com/oss/v2/buckets' -X 'POST' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -H 'Authorization: Bearer TOKEN' -d '{"bucketKey":"kumkortbucket170214","policyKey":"transient"}'
```

Note I'm uploading without content-type and content-length, not need actually:

```
curl -v 'https://developer.api.autodesk.com/oss/v2/buckets/kumkortbucket170214/objects/drawing1.dwg' -X 'PUT' -H 'Authorization: Bearer TOKEN' -T '/Users/augustogoncalves/Desktop/Drawing1.dwg'
```

And finally the POST JOB:

```
curl -X 'POST' -H 'Authorization: Bearer TOKEN' -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -v 'https://developer.api.autodesk.com/modelderivative/v2/designdata/job' -d '{"input":{"urn":"dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6a3Vta29ydGJ1Y2tldDE3MDIxNC9kcmF3aW5nMS5kd2c="},"output":{"formats":[{"type": "svf","views": ["2d","3d"]}]}}'
```

And worked fine

```
{  
   "result":"success",
   "urn":"dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6a3Vta29ydGJ1Y2tldDE3MDIxNC9kcmF3aW5nMS5kd2c",
   "acceptedJobs":{  
      "output":{  
         "formats":[  
            {  
               "type":"svf",
               "views":[  
                  "2d",
                  "3d"
               ]
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: still getting the same error. Should i use the same POST command? @AugustoGoncalves

Comment: reposted my answer, take a look

Comment: I tried some other files and some worked and some of them didnt. All of them worked on the online viewer though. Is there some kind of manual for what type of files that works? all versions of autocad, fonts etc? Thank you for all your help. Cheers

Comment: I would not expect limitations there, but if you can share one of the problematic files, I can investigate better. You can forward to forge.help at autodesk.com

Comment: Hi, i added a link to a file that i have trouble with. @AugustoGoncalves

Comment: thanks for the file, but still working fine (post JOB): {"result":"success","urn":"dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6a3Vta29ydGJ1Y2tldDE3MDIxNC9FS0IuZHdn"........  and get Manifest also works fine: {"type":"manifest","hasThumbnail":"true","status":"success","progress":"complete","region":"US","urn":"dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6a3Vta29ydGJ1Y2tldDE3MDIxNC9FS0IuZHdn","version":"1.0","derivatives":[{"name":"EKB.dwg","hasThumbnail":"true".....